# Fluxion doesn't start capitive portal in Ubuntu 19.10 VM

Tags: wireless, monitoring, hacking

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 in VirtualBox with host Windows 7. I tried to hack my Wi-Fi with Fluxion tool. Everything worked till I tried to open capitive portal. First I didn't get any errors, it just didn't do anything. Then I checked an saw that my Wi-Fi dongle (802.11n) wasn't in monitor mode. After I changed the mode to monitor I got this error:

```
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=fluxw10v disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Driver initialization failed.
fluxw10v: Interface state UNINITIALIZED-> DISABLED
fluxw10v: AP-DISABLED
fluxw10v: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
hostpd_free_hapd_data: Interface fluxw10v wasn't started.
```

I tried to kill `hostpd` but it didn't work either. I got this error:

```
Failed to start hostapd.service: Unit hostapd.service is masked. #1018
```

I unmasked it but it still didn't started the service. I don't know if stopping and restarting `hostapd` will work though.

Comment: Ubuntu 18?   Desktop and Server releases use a *year.month* format for releases, *year* is used only for specialist releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances. Is this an IoT appliance and you're talking about Ubuntu Core 18?  What error message did you get? and what exactly was the problem?  The older versions imply it want an old ABI/API but you gave no details, nor versions detail of kernel/libraries so we could try and understand the issue.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry for not giving the error or the correct version. I added them to the question. I'm a newbie in ubuntu so forgive me :)